# Onclick or href not working on Dropdown menu on hover effect

Tags: javascript, css, html, dropdown

I have a menu with drop down on hover and when clicked it should open a new page.
Here is the HTML;

```
<ul class=“Mainmenu” id=“Mainmenu”>
<li class=“dropdown”><a onclick=“window.location.reload()”>Home</a></li>
<li class=“dropdown”><a href=“Page1.html” onclick=“Loadpage(); return false;”>About us</a>
<ul class=“dropdown-menu” id=“menu1”>
<li class=“dropdownlink” id=“link1”><a href=“#”>Domestic</a></li>
<li class=“dropdownlink” id=“link2”><a href=“#”>International</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class=“dropdown”><a onclick=“Loadteampage(); return false;”>Team</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function Loadpage(){
window.location.href=“Page1.html”;
}
function Loadteampage(){
window.location.href=“Team.html”;
}
```

Here is the CSS

```
.Mainmenu{ 
height: 15px; 
font-family: Calibri;
font-size 12. 5px; 
display: inline; 
position: absolute; 
width: 100%;
line-height: 15px; 
text-align: center; 
list-style: none; 
top 18px;
}

.Mainmenu a{
float: left;
font-size: 14px; 
color: #FAF6AF; 
text-align: center; 
padding: 5px 10px; 
text-decoration: none; 
height: 15px; 
line -height: 15px; 
transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

ul.Mainmenu > li{
float: left; 
position: relative;
}

ul.Mainmenu li > a{
height: 15px; 
line-height: 15px; 
text-align: Center; 
display: block; 
background: #000000; 
color: #FAF6AF; 
white-space: nowrap; 
}

ul.Mainmenu li:hover > a{
background-color: #FAF6AF; 
color #000000; 
cursor: pointer;}

ul.Mainmenu > li ul {
display: none; 
position: absolute;
}

ul.Mainmenu > li:hover ul{
display: block; 
cursor: pointer;
}

ul.Mainmenu > li ul li{
display: block; 
position: relative; 
top: 25px; 
left: -40px;
}

.dropdownlink a{
text-align: center; 
line-height: 15px; 
font-size: 12.5px; 
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
margin: 0; 
width: 100%; 
}
```

The “About us” should act as dropdown when hovered on and act as link when clicked. But the onclick and href on “About us” is not working. Even I tried alert(); in onclick but it’s not working.

Please find the JSFIDDLE Link below:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9u1pdqtv/)

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you redirecting with javascript, instead of simply using the `<a href="..."` attribute?

Comment: @cale_b the <a href=“Page1.html”> was not working, so tried adding JavaScript function to it with onclick, but still no luck.

Comment: Keep things simple: remove the javascript, and focus on the href.  The href will work, unless your markup is malformed.  But the markup you've included is NOT malformed, so I'm suspecting something else is at play here.  Remember - when you're having troubles, _simplify_ - that's how you end up with either a solution to your own problem, or a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @cale_b href was my first choice, but I am guessing it’s issue with css, as this only happens for menu items with dropdown. Other href/onclick functions for other menu items works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Edited to include my favorite expand a list javascript

```
/*

CollapsibleLists.js

An object allowing lists to dynamically expand and collapse

Created by Stephen Morley - http://code.stephenmorley.org/ - and released under
the terms of the CC0 1.0 Universal legal code:

http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/legalcode

*/

// create the CollapsibleLists object
var CollapsibleLists =
    new function(){

      /* Makes all lists with the class 'collapsibleList' collapsible. The
       * parameter is:
       *
       * doNotRecurse - true if sub-lists should not be made collapsible
       */
      this.apply = function(doNotRecurse){

        // loop over the unordered lists
        var uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
        for (var index = 0; index < uls.length; index ++){

          // check whether this list should be made collapsible
          if (uls[index].className.match(/(^| )collapsibleList( |$)/)){

            // make this list collapsible
            this.applyTo(uls[index], true);

            // check whether sub-lists should also be made collapsible
            if (!doNotRecurse){

              // add the collapsibleList class to the sub-lists
              var subUls = uls[index].getElementsByTagName('ul');
              for (var subIndex = 0; subIndex < subUls.length; subIndex ++){
                subUls[subIndex].className += ' collapsibleList';
              }

            }

          }

        }

      };

      /* Makes the specified list collapsible. The parameters are:
       *
       * node         - the list element
       * doNotRecurse - true if sub-lists should not be made collapsible
       */
      this.applyTo = function(node, doNotRecurse){

        // loop over the list items within this node
        var lis = node.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (var index = 0; index < lis.length; index ++){

          // check whether this list item should be collapsible
          if (!doNotRecurse || node == lis[index].parentNode){

            // prevent text from being selected unintentionally
            if (lis[index].addEventListener){
              lis[index].addEventListener(
                  'mousedown', function (e){ e.preventDefault(); }, false);
            }else{
              lis[index].attachEvent(
                  'onselectstart', function(){ event.returnValue = false; });
            }

            // add the click listener
            if (lis[index].addEventListener){
              lis[index].addEventListener(
                  'click', createClickListener(lis[index]), false);
            }else{
              lis[index].attachEvent(
                  'onclick', createClickListener(lis[index]));
            }

            // close the unordered lists within this list item
            toggle(lis[index]);

          }

        }

      };

      /* Returns a function that toggles the display status of any unordered
       * list elements within the specified node. The parameter is:
       *
       * node - the node containing the unordered list elements
       */
      function createClickListener(node){

        // return the function
        return function(e){

          // ensure the event object is defined
          if (!e) e = window.event;

          // find the list item containing the target of the event
          var li = (e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement);
          while (li.nodeName != 'LI') li = li.parentNode;

          // toggle the state of the node if it was the target of the event
          if (li == node) toggle(node);

        };

      }

      /* Opens or closes the unordered list elements directly within the
       * specified node. The parameter is:
       *
       * node - the node containing the unordered list elements
       */
      function toggle(node){

        // determine whether to open or close the unordered lists
        var open = node.className.match(/(^| )collapsibleListClosed( |$)/);

        // loop over the unordered list elements with the node
        var uls = node.getElementsByTagName('ul');
        for (var index = 0; index < uls.length; index ++){

          // find the parent list item of this unordered list
          var li = uls[index];
          while (li.nodeName != 'LI') li = li.parentNode;

          // style the unordered list if it is directly within this node
          if (li == node) uls[index].style.display = (open ? 'block' : 'none');

        }

        // remove the current class from the node
        node.className =
            node.className.replace(
                /(^| )collapsibleList(Open|Closed)( |$)/, '');

        // if the node contains unordered lists, set its class
        if (uls.length > 0){
          node.className += ' collapsibleList' + (open ? 'Open' : 'Closed');
        }

      }

    }();
```

the Html recommended is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Vakram Mohan Help</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en">       

   <script type="text/javascript" src="CollapsibleLists.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<UL id="Mainmenu">
    <li>
        <h2><span>Menu</span></h2>
        <ul>
            <li> <span><a onclick=“window.location.reload()”>Home</a></span></li>

            <li><span><a href="#" onclick="return btntest_onclick()">About us</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span><a href=“#”>Domestic</a></span></li>
                    <li><span><a href=“#”>International</a></span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>



        </ul>
    </li><!--Menu end -->
</UL> <!-- Main Menu end -->

</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function btntest_onclick() 
{
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
</script>
<script>
    CollapsibleLists.applyTo(document.getElementById('Mainmenu'));

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Notice i am not using your CSS file. 
it was a mess

```
#para1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
```

that is a ID selector

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
```

that is a Class selector.

Reset.css is here

```
html, body, header, footer, hgroup, nav, main, article, section, figure, figcaption, h1, h2, h3, ul, li, body, div, p, img
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   border: 0;
}
```

Comment: On a side note.. I do not think you should have Class= Mainmenu be the same name as the id

Comment: the ID and class name does not create any problem so far, I get the css effect correctly. But I can’t get the result in your code, the link works but not the css effects. Can you please give me the reset.css and mainmenu.css?

Comment: Here is an example of that expandable list on a live site.http://www.jeremiahstillings.net/naroggsplace/Solstice.html

Comment: If my solution was not what you hoped for try this resource https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Comment: Aye carumba.  Why so much code, so little explanation, for something that should be fairly simple to resolve?

Comment: @JeremiahStillings with all due respect, this is not what I am looking for, ☹️ I want the hover and onclick/href to work on the dropdown menu, as this is a committed prod site, I can’t add external js or make changes to layout. I have edited my css in the question. Can you help to make my code work?

Comment: @cale_b is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: @JeremiahStillings my dropdown works perfect in hover, only the onclick or href is not working!

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="return btntest_onclick()">About us</a>

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function btntest_onclick() 
{
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
</script>

Comment: @JeremiahStillings creating jsfiddle! Will update it soon!

Comment: Change this line here <li class=“dropdown”><a href=“Page1.html” onclick=“Loadpage(); return false;”>About us</a>

Comment: to read <li><a href="#" onclick="return Loadpage()">About us</a>

Comment: @JeremiahStillings I have updated the jsfiddle link in the question.  https://jsfiddle.net/9u1pdqtv/  I want to make both the hover and onclick to work.

Comment: Sorry Vikram. I think you have to settle for Onclick or hover. I do not know how to make a event listener for both items on the same element

Comment: @JeremiahStillings that’s ok! Thanks for your time anyway!